# How can I modify DOM value batch?

Tags: html, dom

I visit a web page that contains so many text area, and I must replace the text to something else.

One text are like this:

```
<input type="text" name="field" value="round(avg(value0),2)">
```

I need replace `round(avg(value0),2)` to `value0`, so I think I can replace `round(avg(` to empty, and then replace `),2)` to empty. But I don't know how to replace this batch (it may have 100 this text).

Comment: Can you use `jQuery`?

Comment: @rhughes No, I can't. BTW, I'm not going to implement a html effect, I just modify html source code.

Comment: So you mean literally modify the HTML in a text editor?

Comment: Depening of the "structure" of the other content. You should have a look at regular expressions. Almost every editor supports seach and replace with regexp.

Comment: @rhughes In fact, I copy the HTML source code to editor and replace them and then paste back. It works anyway. Thanks

Comment: @MoreFreeze I'm pleased. Did you do it in the way my answer below mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

If you open your HTML document in `Visual Studio` and then press `Ctrl+Shift+H`, it will open the follow dialog box:

[image: Replace in Files]

Select `Current Document` in the `Look in:` dropdown.

Enter what you want to find in the `Find what:` box and then keep the `Replace with:` box blank, then click `Replace All`. This will replace all of those instances with blank text, effectively removing the instances.